# How can i extract a username from string using regexp in php

Tags: php, javascript, regex, extract, match

How can i extract a username from string using **regexp** in **php**

```
<?php

$myString = "user=anas fares,pass=245654323456543dfgf345rgghf5y";

//result should be :

$username = "anas fares";
$password = "245654323456543dfgf345rgghf5y";

//remember, I dont know if username is anas fares or anything else.

?>
```

Comment: I am too tired to answer this right now, but here is a good resource that might help you http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html

Comment: @typoknig ROTFLMAO. this kind won't even bother to click. Why bother to learn or work hard, if there is stackoverflow?

Comment: What is exacetly your problem? Building a regex or using PHP functions? You really should learn using regex with PHP functions.

Comment: I can't learn regexp from english sources because my english isn't good and there aren't regexp sources in my language. :)

Comment: Ara there any simple sources ?

Comment: Well, if you can't learn regex, just use regular string functions as it was proposed by Alin. Not a big deal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A. Non-regex approach.

```
// deprecated //
list($username, $password) = explode(',', $myString);
$username = explode('=', $username);
$username = str_replace('+', ' ', $username[1]);
$password = explode('=', $password);
$password = $password[1];

// new version, independent of order //
$pairs = explode(',', $myString);
foreach($pairs as $pair){
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $pair);
    $results[$key] = str_replace('+', ' ', $value);
}
// $results['user']
// $results['pass']
```

B. Regex.

```
/^user=([^,]*),pass=(.*)$/
```

C. [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). This one **I recommend** and it's probably the best option.

```
parse_str(str_replace(',', '&', $myString), $results);
```

Comment: Ok, I added the regex too, but I do not recommend it.

Comment: @faressoft HEY! You aren't in the restaurant! Upvote the answer and say "Thank you sir, I appreciate your effort but can I please ask for regexp?"

Comment: @Col : I don't know ! what is your problem :0

Comment: @Alin as a matter of fact, your argument is silly and ignorant anyway.

Comment: @Col. You're comments are becoming tiresome. You have an attitude even worse than mine.

Comment: C won't work. You need to specify `$results` as a parameter for `parse_str`. As this function was intended for query string parsing, the contents are being urldecoded too, so you need to urlencode it and replace the `%3D` by `=`: `parse_str(str_replace(',', '&', str_replace('%3D', '=', urlencode($myString))), $results);`.

Comment: nothing wrong with my comments. Your argument coming from rumor, not from real experience and as a result it's false. That's wrong with it.

Comment: @Lekensteyn same to you. Try to run this code and **then** say it won't work.

Comment: @Col, his code was wrong (look at edits). The code is still wrong, I tried `parse_str(str_replace(',', '&', 'a=+,d=%20'), $results);print_R($results);`. `+` and `%20` becomes a space character, which is different from method A and B. The codes I'm commenting on and which I'm posting are both tested.

Comment: @Lekensteyn lol. okay it will fail on some characters. But you can't just say "won't work". Especially if it works perfectly with given example.

Comment: Why are you arguing over presumed formats? The asker supplied just an example. If the code doesn't meet his needs let him tell that. Or better still, he can fiddle with it to work for his data.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru "You're comments are becoming tiresome. You have an attitude even worse than mine."  I have to agree.  @Col. Shrapnel you obviously have some skill, but your soft skills are lacking.  I have yet to see an answer/comment of yours that does not come off as abrasive.  Leaving the attitude out would be much more constructive.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(preg_match('/^user=(.+?),pass=(.+?)$/', $myString, $matches)){// if there's no match, this won't be executed
   $username = $matches[1];
   $password = $matches[2];
}
```

If you know what characters are allowed, it's recommended to use character classes instead or `.`. E.g., you know that the password only contains characters a-z (lowercase only) and 0-9, you should replace the second (.+?) by `[a-z0-9]+?`. If you even know it's a fixed length , in case of a MD5 hash, you should replace `+?` by `{32}` (md5 has a fixed length of 32)